# Когда применяют content:""; в css?

Tags: css

Кто-то может обьяснить когда применяют **content:"";** в `css`?

Именно в таком виде, с пустым местом между кавычками.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если именно "с пустым местом между кавычками", то лично я использую для создания "элемента призрака", с помощью которого центрирую объект. Устанавливаю элемент призрак с высотой 100%  внутри родительского элемента, а затем используем свойство vertical-align: middle для обоих внутренних элементов (центрируемый элемент и элемент призрак):

```
/* Это родитель. Он может иметь любую ширину и высоту */
.block {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Элемент призрак, для центрирования */
.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Задаем небольшой отступ */
}

/* Элемент для центрирования.
   Он может иметь любую ширину и высоту */
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
}
```

P.S. Это конечно лишнее, если вы используете таблицы, но для дивов - полезно

Comment: Я немного заслоупочил, но черт возьми, отличный способ центрирования елемента! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Это используется либо для отмены предыдущего значения, либо для вставки пустого элемента, с возможностью стилизации:

```
<style type="text/css">span.aft:after{content:"";border:2px red solid;width:10px;height:10px;display:inline-block}</style>
<span class="aft">lalala</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что в случае, когда нужно отменить предыдущее значение. Например, когда для списка применено: li:after {content:attr(href)}, а для отдельного элемента требуется отменить это правило.
Другого объяснения на ум не приходит.

Answer (score 0):

На htmlbook понятно написано

Свойство content позволяет вставлять генерируемое содержание в текст веб-страницы, которое первоначально в тексте отсутствует. Применяется совместно с псевдоэлементами :after и :before, они соответственно указывают отображать новое содержимое после или до элемента, к которому добавляются.

[читать полностью](http://htmlbook.ru/css/content)